# Mapping roles to users while migrating

Tags: 8, migrations

Following [this][1], I have  done migration for users from Drupal 7 to Drupal 8, but I got stuck with assigning roles to the specified users.

In user.php file, my code for mapping roles to assigned users is the following.

```
public function prepareRow(Row $row) {
    $uid = $row->getSourceProperty('uid');
    // user_role

    $result = $this->getDatabase()->query('
      SELECT
        r.rid, r.name, ur.uid
      FROM
        {role} r, {users_roles} ur
      WHERE
        r.rid = ur.rid
      AND
        ur.uid = :uid
    ', array(':uid' => $uid));
    foreach ($result as $record) {
      $row->setSourceProperty('roles', $record->name );
    }

    // local_market field of type entity_reference
    $result = $this->getDatabase()->query('
      SELECT
        fld.field_local_market_target_id
      FROM
        {field_data_field_local_market} fld
      WHERE
        fld.entity_id = :uid
    ', array(':uid' => $uid));
    foreach ($result as $record) {
      if (!is_null($record->tids)) {
        $row->setSourceProperty('local_market', explode(',', $record->tids) );
      }
    }



    return parent::prepareRow($row);
  }
```

Except `roles` and custom field, `field_local_market`, all users migrated from Drupal 7 to Drupal 8.

```
destination:
  plugin: entity:user

process:
  uid: uid
  name: name
  pass: pass
  mail: mail
  status: status
  created: created
  changed: changed
  access: access
  login: login
  timezone: timezone
  langcode: language
  preferred_langcode: language
  preferred_admin_langcode: language
  init: init
  field_local_market: local_market 
  field_user_role: user_role
```

What's the right way to assign roles to the users?

Migration of roles is done from Drupal 7 to Drupal 8 by using `drush migrate_upgrade`; the only task left is assigning/mapping these roles to certain UIDs or users.

Answer (score 7):

You can migrate users with roles without migrating roles using migrate **static_map**

In migrate set

```
  process:
  uid: null
  name: name
  pass: pass
  mail: mail
  status: status
  created: created
  access: access
  login: login
  roles:
    plugin: static_map
    bypass: true
    source: roles
    map:
      5: new_role_name
      3: editor
```

and in the source plugin you have to set the roles in **prepareRow**

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function prepareRow(Row $row) {
    $uid = $row->getSourceProperty('uid');

    $query = $this->select('users_roles', 'r');
    $query->fields('r', ['rid']);
    $query->condition('r.uid', $uid, '=');
    $record = $query->execute()->fetchAllKeyed();
    $row->setSourceProperty('roles', array_keys($record));

    return parent::prepareRow($row);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things you can try:

1) You need to pass the Role ID instead of the Role name.

2) Ensure you're passing an array and you actually have results in the query result:

```
$roleIds = array_map(function ($record){
  return $record->rid;
}, $result);

// Make sure $roleIds is an array.    
$row->setSourceProperty('roles', $roleIds);
```

3) As your roles are migrated in another migration, the mapping should be done by using a special plugin "migration". E.g:

```
roles:
  plugin: migration
  source: roles
  migration: the_migration_name_which_migrated_user_roles
```