# How to migrate multi role to an user using migrate csv plugin

Tags: 8, migrations

I have migrated bunch of users using the [Migrate Source CSV](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/migrate-source-csv/using-the-migrate-source-csv-plugin) and am succeeded in it, But I want multi-roles to be defined for single user.

Here is my config file,

[image]

Here is my following cases that I have tried out in a CSV file and it failed,

[image]

Is there is anything am missing out?

Answer (score 3):

First put your all roles inside double quote separating by comma (,) and be sure that your all roles on csv file must be role's machine name.

[image: sample data of user.]

then edit your config file something like this....

```
process: 
  name: name
  mail: email
  pass: password
  roles:
    plugin: explode
    delimiter: ','
    source: roles
  status: status
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:user'
  md5_passwords: true
```

you have to use `plugin: explode` provided by drupal to import multiple roles separated by comma (,).

And if you are importing `password` also then use `md5_passwords: true`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue those days and I came up with the following workaround (I don't think is the best but at least works!)

You roles should be comma separated in the CSV. Also, I had to make the match between the rids as in D7 the rid where numbers (eg 1,2,4) and in D8 it was strings (eg admin, default_role, etc)

Create a custom module only for the migration and use `hook_user_presave` in your module file.

```
//check if the user has multiple roles comma separated
if( strpos($current_roles[1], ',') !== false )
{
  //split the roles
  $tmp = explode(', ', $current_roles[1]);
  foreach ($tmp as $role){
    //add each role separately to the user
    $user->addRole($role);
  }

  //remove the old roles added by the CSV (all user roles comma separated)
  $user->removeRole($current_roles[1]);
}
else{
  // Default role assigned to all other users - optional
  $user->addRole('default_role');
}
```

Also another way to do that is [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/242327/mapping-roles-to-users-while-migrating) but I didn't try it so I don't know if/how it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is with ref to Drupal 8/9

Create your CSV with Roles column containing : **machine_name** only seperated by only comma and no spaces around ex; **role_update,role_create**

Update CSV data accordingly, this is an example for reference

```
First Name Last Name Name      E-Mail     Roles
fname      lname     username  user@email role_update,role_create # No Space in the Cell of Roles data
```

Keep your CSV at public folder : **webroot/sites/default/files/User-List-D7.csv**

YML file should include the import in following way:

```
id: user_migration_csv
migration_tags: null
migration_group: Usermigration
label: 'User migration from CSV'
source:
  plugin: csv
  path: public://User-List-D7.csv
  header_row_count: 1
  ids:
    - ID   
process:
  field_first_name: First Name
  field_last_name: Last Name
  name: Name
  mail: E-mail
  roles:
    plugin: explode
    delimiter: ','
    source: Roles
```